# How to read array and combine with unique ID?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to read from logs and generate a report, the logs have a prefix format like below example:

```
If JobType ID equal to 1 then it will have format "JobType UserName UserID"  
If JobType ID equal to 2 then it will have format "JobType JobID UserID Action Result"
```

Sample:

```
1,Allan,12334
1,Kath,12335  
2,001,12334,Send,Success
2,002,12335,Recv,Success
2,003,12334,Recv,Fail
1,Grace,12336
2,004,12336,Send,Success
```

My end result should be:

```
Job 001, Allan send successfully
Job 002, Kath receive successfully
Job 003, Allan receive failed
```

I'm able to split the array for variable, but I'm not sure how to combine the UserID in different line and generate the result?

Sample script:

```psh
$Logs = Get-content logs.txt
Foreach ($line In $Logs) {
  if ($line[0] -eq "1") {
    $JobType, $Username, $UserID = $line -split ','

    Write-host $JobType
    Write-host $Username
    Write-host $UserID
  } elseif ($line[0] -eq "2") {
    $JobType, $JobID, $UserID, $Action, $Result  = $line -split ',' 

    Write-host $JobType
    Write-host $JobID 
    Write-host $UserID  
    Write-host $Action  
    Write-host $Result
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right, you are asking, how to join different lines from your `logs.txt` over a corresponding  `UserID`. You could do this by building a hashtable that maps user IDs to usernames:

```
$Logs = Get-Content .\logs.txt

$userMap = @{}
$jobLog = @()
foreach ($line In $Logs)
{
    if ($line[0] -eq '1')
    {
        $null, $Username, $UserID = $line -split ','
        $userMap[$UserID] = $Username
    }

    elseif ($line[0] -eq '2')
    {
        $jobLog += $line
    }
    # Do whatever is appropriate for logs with different IDs
}
```

Now you can generate your desired result from the remaining lines by substitution. You may also want to use an extra hastable, to substitute keywords like 'Recv':

```
$keywordMap = @{ 
    'Send' = 'send' 
    'Recv' = 'receive'
    'Success' = 'successfully'
    'Fail' = 'failed' 
}
foreach ($line in $jobLog)
{
    $null, $JobID, $UserID, $Action, $Result = $line -split ','
    Write-Output ('Job {0}, {1} {2} {3}' -f $JobID,
        $userMap[$UserID], $keywordMap[$Action], $keywordMap[$Result])
}
```

Comment: Just change what comes after `Write-Output`. I'm sure, you can figure this out yourself ;) See here for an explanation of the `-f` operator: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: Yes :) That's what i need. but it return in this.. seem repeated. 

My logs.txt  
`1,Allan,12334`  
`1,Kath,12335`  
`2,001,12334,Send,Success`  
`2,002,12335,Recv,Success`  
`2,003,12334,Recv,Fail`  
  
Result:    
`Job 001, Allan send successfully`  
`Job 001, Allan send successfully`  
`Job 002, Kath receive successfully`  
`Job 001, Allan send successfully`  
`Job 002, Kath receive successfully`   

Can you also explain, for the 'Job {0}, {1} {2} {3}'?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) for building output strings like that, and use a [`switch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement to distinguish between the cases:

```
$JobType, $data = $line -split ',', 2
switch ($JobType) {
  1 {
    $Username, $UserID = $data -split ','
    '{0} {1} {2}' -f $JobType, $Username, $UserID
  }
  2 {
    $JobID, $UserID, $Action, $Result  = $data -split ',' 
    '{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}' -f $JobType, $JobID, $UserID, $Action, $Result
  }
  default { "Unknown job type: $JobType" }
}
```

Comment: How do i return the Username match to the UserID? My end result should be `Job 001, Allan send successfully` after it read the Jobtype 1 and Jobtype 2 information.

Comment: @AllanTeoh Split the job type before splitting the rest of the line. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead...

```
$Logs = Get-content logs.txt 

$Type1 = $Logs | ? {$_ -match "^1"}
$Type2 = $Logs | ? {$_ -match "^2"}

$T1Header = "JobType","UserName","UserID"
$T2Header = "JobType","JobID","UserID","Action","Result"

$CSVT1 = ConvertFrom-Csv $Type1 -Delimiter "," -Header $T1Header
$CSVT2 = ConvertFrom-Csv $Type2 -Delimiter "," -Header $T2Header
```

It will create for you 2 CSV files each with required header